# Any way to paste 2 lines at a time in a Windows program and cycle to the next set of 2 lines after each paste?

Tags: windows-10

I'm doing some data entry into a program. I used a batch file to convert my list of entries into the proper format of 2 lines of text each. Now I need to copy/paste a large number of 2 lines at a time into a Windows program

Is there any way to copy the whole list block of hundreds/thousands of lines and paste 2 lines at a time and cycle through to the next set of 2 lines into the program? It's more time consuming than I want to spend if I don't have to.

I've looked at the database for this program and I can't just copy/paste directly into it because it uses long alphanumerical identifiers in each entry that would be impossible to replicate manually.

Here's an example of the format. They need to be pasted in pairs

```
Name "NAME1"
Match [Series] contains all of "NAME1"
Name "NAME2"
Match [Series] contains all of "NAME2"
Name "NAME3"
Match [Series] contains all of "NAME3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **PowerShell** way to read a data file & copy 2 lines to the clipboard, Pause until you press `Enter`, then copy the next two lines to the Clipboard. No clue where or how you're pasting. It would be great if **PowerShell** could detect the `Paste` event & then copy the next lines without a keypress, but I don't know if that's possible.

```
$In = Get-Content 'c:\path\data.txt'
For($i = 0; $i -lt $In.Count; $i = $i + 2 ) {
echo "inloop"
$In[$i] + "`n" + $In[$i + 1] | Set-Clipboard
Pause
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works really well for what I'm doing and cuts out quite a bit of the unnecessary, repetitive work I would have had to do otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.